# Using a preposition with the verb "passen"

Tags: difference, preposition, verb

What is the difference between using "in" and "zu" with the verb "passen". For example:

> Es kommt mir vor, als würde ich nicht **in dieses** Team passen.
>
> Es kommt mir vor, als würde ich nicht **zu diesem** Team passen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the same as between *zusammenpassen* ('to fit together, to go well together') and *hineinpassen* ('to fit in').

When you say *Ich passe **in** dieses Team*, it means you *are in* the team or *could be well in* the team. It's a (maybe even metaphorical) analogy to *Die Schraube passt in das Loch*. It's to be understood like *there's space for you* or *you complete the team as the missing link*.

*Ich passe **zu** diesem Team* means *I go well together with this team*, which needn't imply that you are *in* (i.e. part of) the team.

Answer (score 1):

Letzteres kannst Du auch benutzen, wenn Du Masseur einer Fußballmannschaft wirst, ersteres nur, wenn Du als Fußballspieler aufgenommen wirst.

Das *zu* passt aber in beiden Fällen.